# Reducing line space in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have text within tikz. How can I reduce the vertical space between all the text lines? For example, between the words 'Upstream' and 'Bias' in the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\draw[<-] node[anchor=north] {$t$} (0,0) -- (10,0) ;


\draw[thick, blue] (0,2)  parabola[bend at end] (7,0.5);
\draw[thick, blue] (7,0.5)  parabola (9,2);


\draw[thick, blue] (0,3)  parabola[bend at end] (3,4);
\draw[thick, blue] (3,4)  parabola (9,3);

\draw[thick,dashed,red] (7,0) coordinate  parabola (7,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,red] (3,0) coordinate  parabola (3,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,black] (5,0) coordinate  parabola (5,8) ;


\draw (8,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center]  {\tiny Upstream Bias};
\draw (6,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center] {\tiny  Upstream Bias};
\draw (4,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center] {\tiny Downstream Bias};
\draw (2,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center]  {\tiny  Downstream Bias};


\draw (10.2,3) node {Production};
\draw (10,2) node {Price};


\draw (5,0) node[anchor=north]  {\tiny Switch of R\&D Bias};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `font=\tiny`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\draw[<-] node[anchor=north] {$t$} (0,0) -- (10,0) ;


\draw[thick, blue] (0,2)  parabola[bend at end] (7,0.5);
\draw[thick, blue] (7,0.5)  parabola (9,2);


\draw[thick, blue] (0,3)  parabola[bend at end] (3,4);
\draw[thick, blue] (3,4)  parabola (9,3);

\draw[thick,dashed,red] (7,0) coordinate  parabola (7,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,red] (3,0) coordinate  parabola (3,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,black] (5,0) coordinate  parabola (5,8) ;


\draw (8,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center,font=\tiny]  {Upstream Bias};
\draw (6,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center,font=\tiny] {Upstream Bias};
\draw (4,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center,font=\tiny] {Downstream Bias};
\draw (2,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center,font=\tiny]  {Downstream Bias};


\draw (10.2,3) node {Production};
\draw (10,2) node {Price};


\draw (5,0) node[anchor=north,font=\tiny]  {Switch of R\&D Bias};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

In your picture, in which all but two texts are tiny, it might be easier to set the font globally to tiny and just put `\normalsize` where needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,font=\tiny]

\draw[<-] node[anchor=north] {$t$} (0,0) -- (10,0) ;


\draw[thick, blue] (0,2)  parabola[bend at end] (7,0.5);
\draw[thick, blue] (7,0.5)  parabola (9,2);


\draw[thick, blue] (0,3)  parabola[bend at end] (3,4);
\draw[thick, blue] (3,4)  parabola (9,3);

\draw[thick,dashed,red] (7,0) coordinate  parabola (7,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,red] (3,0) coordinate  parabola (3,8) ;
\draw[thick,dashed,black] (5,0) coordinate  parabola (5,8) ;


\draw (8,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center]  {Upstream Bias};
\draw (6,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center] {Upstream Bias};
\draw (4,8) node [draw, text width=1.1cm, align=center] {Downstream Bias};
\draw (2,8) node [text width=1.1cm, align=center]  {Downstream Bias};


\draw (10.2,3) node[font=\normalsize] {Production};
\draw (10,2) node[font=\normalsize] {Price};


\draw (5,0) node[anchor=north]  {Switch of R\&D Bias};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

[image]